# Optimal settings for serving images with ImageProcessor AzureBlobCache

Tags: azure, imageprocessor

I've been trying to understand the issues https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/161 and https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/178 discusses here.

I have an environment where i have my regular site on http://example.com and i have a separate site for imageprocessor served from http://d.example.com.

Then i have the Azure blob cache setup like this.

```
    <setting key="CachedStorageAccount" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***********;AccountKey=************" />
    <setting key="CachedBlobContainer" value="imgcache" />
    <setting key="UseCachedContainerInUrl" value="false" />
    <setting key="CachedCDNRoot" value="https://imgcdn.azureedge.net/" />
    <setting key="SourceStorageAccount" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=**********;AccountKey=***************" />
    <setting key="SourceBlobContainer" value="dist" />
    <setting key="StreamCachedImage" value="false" />
```

It seems to work fine but i'm not sure about what is my optimal setting for the "StreamCachedImage" option.

I did some tests locally and with StreamCachedImage set to false it do a redirect to the CDN and i get a 302 and then a 200 from the CDN, and chrome says it cached so just a few bytes is transferred.

First: 
[image]

Second:
[image]

When i switch to StreamCachedImage true i do not get a redirect and only get a 200 but it seems like it always returns the full image to the client.

[image]

I should also add that on top of this we also run Cloudflare against both example.com and d.example.com

But well, i basically would like to get some advice on how to set this up and to understand it fully.